# "Вот(,) в чем дело"

Tags: пунктуация

"Вот(,) в чем дело" — нужна ли запятая после "вот"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. 
Понятно, что вас смущает конструкция, похожая на придаточное предложение,  "**в чём дело**", тем более, что "чём" здесь не вопросительное, а относительное местоимение. 
Но, во-первых,  придаточное не может относиться к **частице** (ВОТ), оставшейся на месте главного предложения "вот то....",  ***усечённого*** для удобства в результате частого употребления. 
А во-вторых, это выражение давно стало **устойчивым**. Я думаю, что **до усечения** оно могло выглядеть так: ***"Вот то, в чём заключается дело"***. Некоторые примеры, приведённые ***olsa***, похожие на Ваш случай,  тоже усечённые сложноподчинённые предложения: ***Вот то, что я тебе скажу, Вот то, по какому поводу мы собрались, Вот тот, на кого надежда, Вот то, в чём состоит вопрос.*** 
Главного предложения не стало, осталась только частица и придаточная часть. Знак не ставится.

Answer (score 0):

**Вот** - частица, часто употребляется для уточнения и усиления значения последующего слова или высказывания в целом: *Вот что я тебе скажу. Вот по какому поводу мы собрались. Вот на кого надежда. Вот в чём вопрос. Вот вас-то мне и надо. Вот здесь он стоял*. Запятая после **вот** в таких контекстах не ставится: "*Вот в чем дело*". (Грамота.ру)